# Combine INDIRECT with IF AND COUNTIF

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm working on a Google Sheets based database for work, which shows availability on the dive boats, which instructors are available etc.

I need to copy some some similar formulas to the rows below. There are 365 rows for each day of the year, and several columns with different formulas I need to copy. Sound's straight-forward enough right, but, there's a couple of things that makes this harder.

Here's one of the formulas...

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(SUP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0),AE3,"")
```

1. I am working from Sheet 'AVL'. It basically references ranges in
   five different sheets in the same workbook to look for a match
   against a list of dive instructors we employ who are available to
   work on a daily basis.
2. I need to copy the formula to the rows directly below, so close to
   200 rows for the remainder of this year, and on a new sheet for
   2017, a further 365 rows.

If I copy as normal on google sheets, > Paste special > Paste formula, the formula increases the row number on the formula by one row. EG:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(SUP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0),AE3,"")
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$T5:$T24,AE4)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$T5:$T24,AE4)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$T5:$T24,AE4)=0,COUNTIF(SUP!$T5:$T24,AE4)=0),AE4,"")
```

That's no good to me, because the ranges I need to reference from the other sheets are completely different, but, the cell referenced with the staff name on, on the sheet I'm working on 'AVL' moves down by one row which is correct.

The ranges from the five other sheets needs to move down by 26 rows each time. EG:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(SUP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0),AE3,"")
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$T30:$T49,AE4)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$T30:$T49,AE4)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$T30:$T49,AE4)=0, COUNTIF(SUP!$T30:$T49,AE4)=0, COUNTIF(OTH!$T30:$T49,AE4)=0),AE4,"")
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$U56:$U75,AE5)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$U56:$U75,AE5)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$U56:$U75,AE5)=0,COUNTIF(SUP!$U56:$U75,AF5)=0, COUNTIF(OTH!$U56:$U75,AE5)=0),AE5,"")
```

Etc etc.

I've used the INDIRECT function previously for something else, and was wondering if I should be looking at combining the formula I used for something else, with the formula I need to copy 1,000's of times. EG...

```
=INDIRECT("CHO!B" & (3 + 26*(ROW()-3)))
```

adjusted and modified and combined with...

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(MER!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(CHO!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0, COUNTIF(KEP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0,COUNTIF(SUP!$T4:$T23,AE3)=0),AE3,"")
```

to somehow increase the ranges by 26 rows every time I copy the formula, while leaving the cell I'm matching against AE3 etc, to just increase by one row.

Comment: Just make the rows absolute `$T$4:$T$23` then it will not change as it is copied down.

Comment: But, I want the rows in the ranges from the other sheets to change by 26 rows each time I copy the formula to the row below. $T4:$T23,AE3 / $T30:$T49,AE34 / $T56:$T75,AE6 etc.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in original question, all ranges are in Col T on the other sheets. I wrote U in one of the examples.

Comment: If it's Google Sheets then remove vba and excel-vba tags from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your cell ranges with a pair of non-volatile¹ [INDEX functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

For example, these two cell ranges are exactly the same.

```
=T4:T23
=INDEX(T:T, 4):INDEX(T:T, 23)
```

The rest is just simple maths and a [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D). Put this in the top row.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(INDEX(MER!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+4):INDEX(MER!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+23), AE3)=0,
        COUNTIF(INDEX(CHO!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+4):INDEX(CHO!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+23), AE3)=0,
        COUNTIF(INDEX(KEP!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+4):INDEX(KEP!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+23), AE3)=0,
        COUNTIF(INDEX(SUP!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+4):INDEX(SUP!$T:$T, (ROW(1:1)-1)*26+23), AE3)=0), AE3, "")
```

Fill down as necessary.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Jeeped, thanks very much, you smashed it! Very helpful, thanks again.